# Determining Exact Values of Trignometric Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

Use the special triangles to give exact 
solutions where possible. Find all values of $x$ such that 
$0\le x \le 2\pi$ .

(a) $\tan^2 x=1$ $\,$
(b)$\, \, 2\cos x + \sqrt{3}=0 \, \,$ 
(c) $\, \, \sin^2 x + 2\cos x-2=0$

Hi, so I've been having issues with these kind of questions lately.  I know the general process of using the CAST rule in order to find the solutions.  However, I am having problems getting these kind of questions started.  I cannot figure out how to interpret what is the first thing I should do. b) looks to be a linear trig function, while a and b look to be exponential.  I'm hoping that someone will be able to "walk" me through these.

Comment: With the last one, it may be beneficial to substitute in $1-\cos^2x$ for $\sin^2x$. (Why can we do this?) It looks like a good idea, because we then have everything in terms of $\cos x$'s. (In particular, you end up with a _quadratic in $\cos x$._)

Comment: Try to forget about Satanic chants such as FOIL, SOHCAHTOA, and CAST, but instead, use your reasoning skills. For example if $\pi\lt\theta\lt\frac{3}{2}\pi$ this would correspond to a negative $x$ and a negative $y$. Use that information to determine the signs of the trigonometric ratios. CAST will only end up teaching you "how not to use your brain".

Answer (score 1):

$a)$: $\tan x = \pm 1\to x = \pi/4, 3\pi/4, 5\pi/4, 7\pi/4$.

$b)$: $\cos x = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\to x = 5\pi/6, 7\pi/6$.

$c)$: $1-\cos^2 x + 2\cos x - 2 = 0 \to \left(\cos x - 1\right)^2 = 0\to \cos x = 1\to x = 0,2\pi$.